# Firefox RotateY Transform not working

Tags: firefox, css-transitions

I have a page that displays pictures of people that can be resized via jQuery.  I am using a sprite image that displays 3 squares that change as you select/hover them.  I am using CSS3 Transition & Transform (RotateY) to animate the change.
The transition and transform works in Chrome (v22), but not in Firefox (v16).

I have create a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/WPEbW/7/

```
<div id="divOptions" runat="server" style="padding: 0 10px; margin: 10px; overflow: hidden; zoom: 1">
    <div style="float: left">
        <div id="divSmallImage" runat="server" class="ResizeImages Small" title="Small">
        </div>
        <div id="divMediumImage" runat="server" class="ResizeImages Medium Selected" title="Medium">
        </div>
        <div id="divLargeImage" runat="server" class="ResizeImages Large" title="Large">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​

.ResizeImages { cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; background-position: 0; -moz-transform:rotateY(0deg) }
.ResizeImages:hover { box-shadow: #CCC 1px 1px 5px; -webkit-transition: none; -moz-transition: none; -o-transition: none; transition: none; }
.ResizeImages.Selected { -webkit-transition: background-position 0 .4s,-webkit-transform 1s; -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); -moz-transition: background-position 0 .4s,-moz-transform 1s; -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg); -o-transition: background-position 0 .4s,-o-transform 1s; -o-transform: rotateY(180deg); transition: background-position 0 .4s,transform 1s; transform: rotateY(180deg); }
.ResizeImages.Small { background: url('https://www.new-innov.com/RMSImages/square_sprite.png') 0 0 no-repeat; width: 12px; height: 12px; }
.ResizeImages.Small:hover { background-position: 0 -12px; }
.ResizeImages.Small.Selected { background-position: 0 -24px; }
.ResizeImages.Medium { background: url('https://www.new-innov.com/RMSImages/square_sprite.png') -12px 0 no-repeat; width: 16px; height: 16px; }
.ResizeImages.Medium:hover { background-position: -12px -16px; }
.ResizeImages.Medium.Selected { background-position: -12px -32px; }
.ResizeImages.Large { background: url('https://www.new-innov.com/RMSImages/square_sprite.png') -28px 0 no-repeat; width: 20px; height: 20px; }
.ResizeImages.Large:hover { background-position: -28px -20px; }
.ResizeImages.Large.Selected { background-position: -28px -40px; }

$(document).ready(function() {
    function SetSize(selectedImage) {
        if (typeof selectedImage !== 'undefined') {
            $('.ResizeImages.Selected').removeClass('Selected');
            $(selectedImage).addClass('Selected');
        }
    }
    SetSize();
    $('.ResizeImages').click(function() {
        SetSize(this);
    });
});​
```

I believe that the transition and transform I am using should work in Firefox, but don't know why they aren't.

Thanks in advance,
-Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Boris Zbarsky, I was able to solve my own issue.  I spelled out the transitions, instead of trying to use the shorthand version for the class.

I updated the jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/WPEbW/10/

Here's the css just the only class I changed:

```
.ResizeImages.Selected { 
    -webkit-transition-property: background-position, -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s, 1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .4s, 0s;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); 
    -moz-transition-property: background-position, -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0s, 1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .4s, 0s;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg); 
    -o-transition-property: background-position, -o-transform;
    -o-transition-duration: 0s, 1s;
    -o-transition-delay: .4s, 0s;
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg); 
    transition-property: background-position, transform;
    transition-duration: 0s, 1s;
    transition-delay: .4s, 0s;
    transform: rotateY(180deg); 
}
```

Comment: @BorisZbarsky I don't follow you.  The '0' I am referring to are for position, not time.

Comment: Your original CSS had things like `transition: background-position 0 0.4s`.  The values there are a property name, a transition delay, and a transition duration.  So the 0 should be 0s for a compliant CSS parser to not throw away the declaration.  Your rewritten CSS correctly uses 0s for the transition duration, so it works.  But it would have also worked to just replace the 0 with 0s in the original CSS.

Answer (score 3):

`background-position 0 .4s` is not a valid `<single-transition>` as defined at http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transitions/#single-transition so your entire `-moz-transition` rule gets discarded by the CSS parser.  As the error console says:

> [03:47:02.876] Error in parsing value for '-moz-transition'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/WPEbW/7/show/:18

It works in Chrome because Chrome unfortunately doesn't actually implement the spec for parsing transition values correctly.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your assistance.  I was able to come up with the solution which I have posted.